# Web method stop working after removing page extension from URL

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, webmethod

I am using the below rule in web.config to remove ".aspx" from URL

```
  <rule name="RemoveASPX" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)\.aspx" />
              <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="AddASPX" enabled="true">
              <match url=".*" negate="false" />
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.aspx" />
          </rule>
```

The page methods are working fine earlier but after adding this rule web.config, they stopped working. If i remove this from web.config they start working. Can anyone explain why this is happening. I have googled but not get any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the rule `AddASPX` is adding the `.aspx` to all the incoming URLs but those that directly refer to a file or directoy, or have a dot.

If your page mehtod urls look like this `path\page.aspx\methodname`, they are not modified because there is a `.` (dot) in it. But, if your urls look like this: `path\page\methodname`, they are rewritten as `path\page\methodname.aspx` and that's why them stop working.

You have to determine a pattern that works for this cases, and implement a condition to ignore it. You need to determine how the failing URLs look like. You can use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or the browser console (press F12 to open it) to see the requested URLs.